# Car parking related probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A driver parks a car in a row of $25$ cars randomly at any place but not ends. After coming back he finds $10$ cars are gone so what is the probability that both the neighbouring cars have gone?

What I did $$\dfrac{{24\choose 8}}{{23\choose 1}{24\choose 10}}$$  $24C8$ as we want two cars to go so we want to select only $8$ cars. And driver can park in $23$ ways and cars can go in $24C10$ ways.

But that doesn't yield the answer what am I missing on? Please any hints using basic probability equations.

Comment: Can you check your spelling please. What is a riw?

Comment: @Stef I think he meant to write row.

Comment: @VarunIyer Ok, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L$ denote the event that his left neighbor has left and $R$
the event that his right neighbor has left. Then:

$$P\left(L\cap R\right)=P\left(L\mid R\right)P\left(R\right)=\frac{9}{23}\frac{10}{24}$$

The second factor because of $24$ cars $10$ leave and all cars have equal chances to be one them. The first factor likewise, but now of $23$ cars $9$ are selected to leave.

Comment: +1, but can I make more step-by-step? The $\Pr(R)=\frac{\binom{23}{9}}{\binom{24}{10}}$, because there are $\binom{24}{10}$ possible groups of $10$ cars leaving, and to count how many include the car to the right, we leave that one out as a given, and for the remaining $9$ cars there'll be $\binom{23}{9}$ possible groupings. Similarly, for $\Pr(L\vert R) = \frac{\binom{22}{8}}{\binom{23}{9}}.$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Out of the $2$ neighbouring cars, both have to go, so you need a term of $2\choose 2$ in the numerator. Now, there are still $10-2=8$ cars to choose from the remaining $25-1-2=22$ cars. These are the favourable cases. All the possible cases are $24 \choose 10$. Do you know what to do next?

---

To compare

> $$\frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{22}{8}}{\dbinom{24}{10}}$$

Comment: Oh thanks i thought we need to exclude cars that will surely go ie neighbouring