# A car is parked by an owner amongst 25 cars in a row not at the two extremes. On his return he find that exactly 15 places are .

Tags: probability

A car is parked by an owner amongst 25 cars in a row not at the two extremes. On his return he find that exactly 15 places are still occupied. Find the probability that both the neighboring places are vacant .

How to approach this problem , not getting any clue. please suggest will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: You have the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1592709/152225)... The subtlety is in counting the favorable outcomes as any combinations of 22 cars, because the ones to either side will be gone.

Comment: There are $10$ vacant slots among the $24$ slots excluding yours. Imagine that they are $10$ "ghost cars", and you want $2$ of these ghost cars in the $2$ slots adjoining you.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- What is the probability that the position on the left is empty?
- Given that the position on the left is empty, what is the probability that the position on the right is empty?